# How to disable radio groups radio buttons using wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a radio group in my web application,I have to disable the radio buttons dynamically when I click some other radio button.
How can we do that using wicket,can someone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `radioGroup.setEnabled(false)` and repaint it. If the request is an Ajax one then you need to add the `radioGroup` to the `AjaxRequestTarget`: `target.add(radioGroup)`. If the request is non-Ajax, i.e. a normal one, then there is nothing to do since the whole page will be repainted, together with the Radio group.

Comment: Thanks ,it works.one more thing would like to know,on page load ,I have to disable the radio buttons,so I added the radio group.setEnable(false) that's works in page load,then when I clicked on the radio buttons to enable or disable,that's not working ,I even added target.add(radiogroup) after enabling or disabling the component.any suggestions?

Comment: Watch out: by default RadioGroup renders its body only, so you can't update it via Ajax. Call #setRenderBodyOnly(false) on it so there's markup for it in the rendering result.